# Create File object (directory or file) in Android as Java on Windows

Tags: java, android, file, path

I need to open a directory or a File as i would do in Windows using Java.

Desktop:
File carpetaXML = new File("C:\Users\CPNBK70\Downloads\FolderXYZ");

Android:
File carpetaXML = new File("/storage/emulated/0/FolderXYZ");

I use the above path, but it doesn't work when listing the files on the directory,

```
public static ArrayList<String> listarXml(File f, ArrayList<String> data) {
    File[] ficheros = f.listFiles();
    for (File fichero : ficheros) {
        if (fichero.isDirectory()) {
            data = listarXml(fichero, data);
        } else if (fichero.getName().endsWith(".xml")) {
            data.add(fichero.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Stacktrace:

```html
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
W/System.err:     at com.neogrid.integratormobile.util.Util.listarXml(Util.java:15)
W/System.err:     at com.neogrid.integratormobile.ActivityMain.firmarDocsCarpeta(ActivityMain.java:42)
W/System.err:     at com.neogrid.integratormobile.ActivityMain$1.onClick(ActivityMain.java:33)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6213)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11074)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23645)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: I'm trying to list all files in the directory, but i get an error: nullPointerException because it can't find the directory

Comment: If you check for null first you would not get an exception. Be prepared for nulls.

Comment: Please show your stacktrace

Comment: Well, `listFiles()` is documented to return `null`. Either that directory does not exist, is not a directory, or you do not have permission to work with [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: *Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory,*

Comment: I would like to know how to access this folder using File object as i do in Windows. Is that path correct? Which path should i use to access the same files i put on internal storage when connecting the phone to a computer?

Comment: and which line is line `15`?

Comment: this: for (File fichero : ficheros) {